# NSUserNotification not showing action button

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion, nsusernotification

I'm using this code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
    [notification setTitle: @"Title"];
    [notification setSubtitle: @"Subtitle"];
    [notification setInformativeText: @"Informative Text"];

    [notification setHasActionButton: YES];
    [notification setActionButtonTitle: @"Action Button"];
    [notification setOtherButtonTitle: @"Other Button"];

    [notification setSoundName: NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName];

    [notification setDeliveryDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 10]];
    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] scheduleNotification: notification];
}
```

And I'm getting, without fail,

[image]

No action button, or other button.

Comment: I can not add comments just below Patrick's answer since I am just a new guy in stackoverflow, but @Dorian, you can check my answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029755/nsusernotificationalertstyle-plist-key-not-working/55320805#55320805
The screen is in the system preference.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

And here was the answer.

Thanks again to #macdev on freenode.

[image]

The selection needs to be "Alerts" to have buttons.

Comment: How did you get to this screen?

Comment: How to use "_displayStyle" to change Alert style?

Answer (score 50):

As already stated in a previous answer, the notification type needs to be set to alert for the action button to be shown.  If you want to set the default notification style of your app to alert, you need to define the key **NSUserNotificationAlertStyle** in info.plist with the value **alert**.

See Apple's [info.plist keys reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW1) for more details:

> **NSUserNotificationAlertStyle** Specifies whether the notification style should be **banners**, **alerts**, or **none**. The default value is banners, which is the recommended style.

Comment: Do you know if anything like this is available for iOS?

Comment: I don't believe this can be configured for UILocalNotifications in iOS with the current APIs.

Comment: And, the app needs to be signed for it to allow buttons.

Answer (score 18):

As a contrary instance for other answers we can use iTunes - it still showing "Skip" button even when we setup alert style to banners. So I continued searching and found [this github repo](https://github.com/indragiek/NSUserNotificationPrivate) where [Indragie Karunaratne](https://github.com/indragiek) provide some useful additional properties in NSUserNotification private headers. You can check for full list of the properties in the *NSUserNotification_Private.h* file, but actual for showing buttons in banner notification style is

```
@property BOOL _showsButtons; // @dynamic _showsButtons;
```

so you can just add this line to you code

```
[notification setValue:@YES forKey:@"_showsButtons"];
```

and your notification action button will become independent on alert style.

Comment: how to add selector for the button in notification?

Comment: How to use "_displayStyle" to change Alert style?

Answer (score 1):

magic command based on PARTISAN's reply is:

```
notification.set_showsButtons_(True)
```

cha-ching :)

Comment: Worked perfectly in PyObjC