# Creating interactive notifications for OS X

Tags: swift, macos, notifications, swift3, nsusernotification

[Mac Basics: Notifications keep you informed](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204079) states that it's possible to create an interactive alert with an text input field:

> For example, you can reply to a chat directly from a notification.
>
> [image: OS X chat alert]

How can I implement it? For instance, I have a notification:

```
let notification = NSUserNotification.init()
notification.hasActionButton = true
notification.actionButtonTitle = "Agree"
notification.title = "Header"
notification.informativeText = "Text."

NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(notification)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Banners, Alerts, and Badges are all types of `NSUserNotification` instances.  The chat reply image is an example of a the `alert` style.

To change the user `NSUserNotification` display style for your application, set the value for `NSUserNotificationAlertStyle` to `alert` in your application's `Info.plist` file.  I should note that there are [known issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16029755/2415822) and [open](http://openradar.appspot.com/12632111) [radars](http://openradar.appspot.com/12632157) with this in the Cocoa SDK.  The [default value](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) for this is `banner`.

You can then use the Display Information and Displayed Notification Buttons to customize the alert.

See the [`NSUserNotification` API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsusernotification) for information on how you can customize the buttons, placeholder text, etc on the alert.

Here's how I did it (Swift 2.2, if you are using Swift 2.3 or 3 your syntax may vary).  The key is to set `hasReplyButton` to `true`.

```
let notification = NSUserNotification()
notification.hasActionButton = true
notification.actionButtonTitle = "Agree"
notification.title = "Title"
notification.informativeText = "Text."
notification.responsePlaceholder = "Placeholder"
notification.hasReplyButton = true

NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().deliverNotification(notification)
```

[image: Alert]

[image: Alert with Reply]

Comment: I've read the documentation, thanks. The only thing that I don't understand is how to create the inline reply field. Any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelSamoylov Updated my answer with an example.