# Set a custom time a NSUserNotification is displayed

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications, nsusernotification, nsusernotificationcenter

I create a `NSUSerNotification` in the following way:

```
NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
[notification setTitle:notificationTitle];
[notification setInformativeText:_informativeText];
[notification setSoundName:NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName];

[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];
```

I want the notification to be displayed for more that a few seconds.
How do I customise the duration the notification is displayed on the screen?

Comment: Default usernotification syle will be __banner__. And banners dont stick around. The other alternative is [changing notification style](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12012934/366346) to __alert__ With this the notification will stick and will be dismissed only when user clicks on it. But I am sure if banner time can be modified.